# Fragment isVisible() true when not

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an Activity with a fragment container and two fragments used like "list fragment -> detail fragment"

```
private boolean isFirstFragmentAdded() {
    return getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("FIRST_FRAGMENT_TAG") != null;
}

private boolean isFirstFragmentVisible() {
    return getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("FIRST_FRAGMENT_TAG").isVisible();
}

private boolean isSecondFragmentAdded() {
    return getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("SECOND_FRAGMENT_TAG") != null;
}

private boolean isSecondFragmentVisible() {
    return getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("SECOND_FRAGMENT_TAG").isVisible();
}

private void addFirstFragment() {
    firstFragment = new FirstFragment();
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, firstFragment, "FIRST_FRAGMENT_TAG").commit();
}

private void showFirstFragment() {
    firstFragment = new FirstFragment();
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, firstFragment, "FIRST_FRAGMENT_TAG").commit();
}

private void addSecondFragment() {
    secondFragment = new SecondFragment();
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, secondFragment, "SECOND_FRAGMENT_TAG").commit();
}

private void showSecondFragment() {
    secondFragment = new SecondFragment();      getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, secondFragment, "SECOND_FRAGMENT_TAG").commit();
}

private void refreshVisibleFragment() {
    if (isFirstFragmentAdded() && isFirstFragmentVisible()) {
        refreshFirstFragment();
    } else if (isSecondFragmentAdded() && isSecondFragmentVisible()) {
        refreshSecondFragment();
    }
}
```

the thing is that even when my SECOND fragment is visible the FIRST one always return `isVisible() == true`, so the second one never refresh. Already try remove, detach and nothing works: the first fragment always appears as added and visible. Also test it in tablet and phones and the same thing happens. Maybe I'm missing something but can't get it right so any help will be appreciated. Thx

Comment: When you add the second fragment, you use the add or you have also tried replacing the current fragment?

Comment: isVisible(): Return true if the fragment is currently visible to the user. This means it: (1) has been added, (2) has its view attached to the window, and (3) is not hidden.

Check the hidden state of the fragment as explained here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onHiddenChanged(boolean) and calling the isHidden() method.

Comment: To replace the fragment i ask if it is already added, if it is added call replace() if not call add(). The state of isHidden() is false for the First fragment while it is not visible to the user, the visible fragment is the Second one

Comment: If isHidden() returns false, then according to the documentation, isVisible() will return true. Check why first fragment is not hidden and/or how to set it hidden programmatically.

Comment: Yes I already try with hide(), remove(), detach() and nothing change, don't know what's going on! My guess is that it has something to do with the fact that I'm creating a new instance of the fragment in the replace but if I get the fragment instead: `firstfragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("FIRST_FRAGMENT_TAG");` and then use that instance in the replace I'm getting an exception that the fragment is already added. According the documentation when a replace is done the previous fragment is removed so how can it return `isVisible() == true`?

Comment: maybe you could work this around changing your logic: keep in a class variable (in the Activity) a reference to the current fragment. Then in order to check which fragment is visible use something like:
if(currentFragment instanceOf FirstFragment) ...

Comment: Fixed already. The problem was that i was adding 2 firstFragment into the fragmentManager so when the replace() is called the fragments weren't deleted and the visibility state never change from true (don't know why, i suppose coz was 2 with the same tag but the logic is that the 2 were deleted) now i manage to have always just 1 fragment in the manager so it's working fine. Anyway there is some weird stuff with the fragmentManager in the support library or i get it all wrong i the documentation. Thanks @fasteque for your time and your help

Comment: guys, I am just wondering based on the definition 'isVisible()' returns true if  fragmen1 added (add method), but fragment 2 or even fragment3 already added, since fragment1 still attached. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

Try
`fragment.isMenuVisible()` instead after setting `fragment.setMenuUserVisibility(false)`